# Why skipping 1st iteration when reading from stdin in java?

Tags: java, string, stdin, palindrome

The below program always skip the 1st iteration.It does not take any input in 1st iteration>What is wrong with this.I am ver new to java so mabe this problem could be very lame. :( below is my program

```
import java.util.*;
public class Solution2 {
    public static void main (String [] args){
    String str;
    int T,length,a;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    T = in.nextInt(); // no of test cases
    int [] oprs = new int [T];
    // taking a string 
    for(int i = 1;i <= T;i++){

         str = in.nextLine();

        int ops = 1;   
        char [] array;
        array = str.toCharArray();
        length = array.length;
        if (length % 2 == 0 ){
            int  k = 1;
            for(int j = length/2 ; j < length ;j++ ){
                if(array[length/2 - k] != array [j]){

                    a = Math.abs((int)array[length/2 - k] - (int)array[j]);
                    ops = ops + a; 
                }
                k++;
            }
            oprs [i - 1] = ops;
        }
        else{
            int k = 1;
            for(int j = (length+1)/2;j < length ; j++){
                if(array[(length-1)/2 - k ] != array [j]){
                    a = Math.abs((int)array[(length-1)/2 - k] - (int)array[j]);
                    ops = ops + a; 
                } 
                k++;  
            }
            oprs [i - 1] = ops;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0;i < T ;i++){
        System.out.println(oprs[i]);
    }
}
}
```

This is the expected input and output

Sample Input
3 
abc 
abcba 
abcd

output 
2 
0 
4

This is what i am getting 
3
abc
abcd

It dosen't let me give the 3rd input.
output
1
3
5

Comment: What are valid inputs to test this out?

Comment: This will return how many iterations should be done to change a string into a palindrome.And T tels how many strings we gonna check

Comment: Darn, why didn't you say that at first! Can you give us an input and output sample please?

Comment: I have no idea what you were asking at all here!

Comment: @Dina There are 2 solutions to avoid is not read in the first iteration of the FOR: 
1).- Placing: str = in.nextLine (); before FOR 
2).- Change the line in the FOR by: str = in.next ();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is you have to capture the new line of in.nextInt (), to which must precede the following line:

```
str = in.nextLine();
```

before the FOR

```
for(int i = 1;i <= T;i++){
```

Comment: @Dina The carriage return isn't consumed by nextInt.

Comment: @Dina Before the first FOR puts it: str = in.nextLine(); 
and your problem will be solved.

Comment: It's because when you enter a number then press Enter, input.nextInt() consumes only the number, not the "end of line", primitive data types like int, double etc does not consume "end of line", due which this "end of line" remain in buffer and When input.nextLine() executes, it consumes the "end of line" from buffer from the first input.

Comment: @JoseLuis I do not know what happened but I tested what you said and I did not need to input.nextLine(). I know what you say but here is irrelevant.

Comment: @KickButtowski input.nextLine () is a general reference, but in this specific case would in.nextLine (). Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
   for(int i = 1;i <= T;i++){
```

you overlooked index `i = 0` because your start point is `i = 1` therefore the first iteration will be missed.

To remind you, In **Java**, array index starts from `0` not `1`.

Comment: good point, then logic of the op code is totally wrong and must be changed

Comment: the op did not say what his code does or explain anything yet

Comment: Can you up vote my comment, since I'm right? His code looks ok. Just trying it out now, but we need to know the input values and expected output...

Comment: Ok, it can't hurt to try ;-)

Comment: Oh thats not it.That loop s to tell how many times a loop should run.It dosen't work with any array.

Comment: what do you mean? so which loops skips? you are **very unclear**

Comment: See guys this is a problem from hacker rank.i already finished it with a little tweak.But i wanna clarify why the 1st iteration missing every time.This is the expected input and output

Comment: Sample Input #00

3
abc
abcba
abcd output ->2
0
4

Comment: changed it --> for(int i = 0;i <T+1;i++){ and changed the index of oprs into oprs[i] now this runs fine.It always skip a 1 iteration earlier.if i wanna run this loop for i times,it just runs i -  1 times.thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution2 {

    public Solution2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main (String [] args){
        String str;
        int T,length,a;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        T = in.nextInt(); // no of test cases 
        int [] oprs = new int [T];
        // taking a string 

        for(int i=1; i<=T; i++){
            //System.out.printf("%d\n",i);
            str = in.next();
            System.out.println(str);
            int ops = 1;

            char [] array;
            array = str.toCharArray();
            length = array.length;
            if (length % 2 == 0 ){
                int  k = 1;
                for(int j = length/2 ; j < length ;j++ ){
                    if(array[length/2 - k] != array [j]){
                        System.out.printf("%c %c\n",array[length/2 - k] ,array [j]);
                        a = Math.abs((int)array[length/2 - k] - (int)array[j]);
                        ops = ops + a;
                    }
                    k++;
                }
                oprs[i - 1] = ops;
            }
            else{
                int k = 1;
                for(int j = (length+1)/2;j < length ; j++){
                    if(array[(length-1)/2 - k ] != array [j]){
                        a = Math.abs((int)array[(length-1)/2 - k] - (int)array[j]);
                        ops = ops + a;
                    }   
                }
                oprs[i - 1] = ops;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0;i < T ;i++){
            System.out.println(oprs[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Tried with input of: 3 abc abcba abcd
and this is the result:

```
abc
abcba
abcd
b c
a d
3
2
5
```

Comment: YUp i edited the code.See the problem is it is not taking the determined number of strings.

Comment: YUp Yup :) If not a problem,use the revised code i provided.I made the problem more understanding